# Why is this ASP Classic process not executing?

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an ASP Classic page which has a button that then opens a popup (just a test for now) to execute a query. However, this query is never executed (also the `Response.Write`is not showing up). Why is this not executing?

Here is the code from the main page. I double-checked and the correct values are being passed to the function.

```
function clearAssignment(assignmentID,docrecid)
{
    window.open("procclearassignment.asp?assignmentID="+assignmentID+"&docrecid="+docrecid,"",'width=375,height=220');
}
<INPUT TYPE="button" class = "sbtn" name="clearassignment" Value="Clear" target="_self" onclick = "clearAssignment(<%=assignmentID%>,<%=docrecid%>);"/>
```

Here is the process:

```
<!--#include file="content/securityheader.asp"-->
<!--#include file="connection.inc"-->
<!--#include file="connectionxref.inc"-->
<!--#include file="securityheader.asp"-->
<!--#include file="connectionSQL.inc"-->

<% 'SQL SECURITY CODE
    function dbencodeStr(str)
        thestr = trim(replace(str,"'","&#39;"))
        thestr = trim(replace(thestr,"""","&#34;"))
        thestr = trim(replace(thestr,"<","&lt;"))
        thestr = trim(replace(thestr,">","&gt;"))
        thestr = trim(replace(thestr,vbCRLF,"<BR>"))
        dbencodeStr = thestr
    end function
%>
<%
Server.ScriptTimeout=3600

'------------------------------
Function getName(str)
index = instr(str," ")
if index > 0 then
str = trim(mid(str,1,index))
end if
getName = str
End Function
'------------------------------

on error resume next

assignmentID = dbencodeStr(request.Form("assignmentID"))
docid = dbencodeStr(request.Form("docrecid"))
thedate = now()

if docid <> "" Then
    ''''Close any open assignments for the document
    strSQL = "update RelDocAssignments set activeflag = 0, closedOn = getdate() where docid = '"&docid&"' and ID = '"&assignmentID&"';"
    Set rs = objConnection.Execute(strSQL, ,adCmdText)
end if
Response.write(strSQL)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

objConnection.close
set objConnection = nothing
objConnection2.close
set objConnection2 = nothing
objConnection3.close
set objConnection3 = nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be passing your values via url/querystring:

```
window.open("procclearassignment.asp?assignmentID="+assignmentID+...
```

But you're retrieving them as if they were POSTed:

```
assignmentID = dbencodeStr(request.Form("assignmentID"))
```

I think you want:

```
assignmentID = dbencodeStr(request.QueryString("assignmentID"))
```

instead.